# Xcode 7.2 Wildcard provisioning profile recognized instead of other profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, provisioning-profile

I have recreated my provisioning profiles, app IDs and certificates and when I go to upload my archive to app store I get the message

[image: error message]

link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT04f.jpg

The bundle identifier in the Xcode general tab is correct and also in the build settings tab it is correct. My bundle identifier is not a wildcard it is explicit. I am out of ideas, thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Can you post what profiles you have installed? Also what is the App Id / Bundle ID your app should be being signed with?

FYI: You can view your downloaded profiles in Xcode under the following menu: XCode -> Preferences ...-> Accounts (Tab) -> Select your Apple ID -> Select your team name -> View Details ...

Comment: I am suppose to be signing with Distribution.PulseMD or Enterprise.PulseMD here is the list of Profile with account.. I don't know how so many got there. http://imgur.com/cLW4OrT

Comment: what is the Bundle ID configured in for your project and associated with these profiles?

Comment: Distribution.PulseMD

Comment: This looks a little unusual for the Bundle Id. Can you double check this. It is shown by selecting your (your) Project -> (your) Target -> General Tab under Identity -> Bundle Id.

Similarly Under the Apple Certificate Portal what is the associate App Id with these provisioning profiles? https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action  These should match. If they don't then this will likely be why Xcode isn't using them.

Comment: They match. Why are there so many XC: profiles? My archive shows the correct identifier as well but when I go to upload to appstore that is when I get the wildcard error.

Comment: Here is the full list of my project settings. :http://imgur.com/a/I86xf
1. Build settings code sign
2. Archive error with identifier showing the correct bundle identifier
3. Project info team 
4. repeat of 1 sorry
There error makes it seem the xcode generated wildcard profile gets in the way but I cannot find out where that happens.

Comment: thanks, the one thing you're missing though is the details off this portal: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action . You should have an App Id matching 'Distribution.PulseMD'

One other thing odd here is that your bundle id isn't using the standard reverse domain format. I don't know if this would cause the problem or not though. If you're still having trouble you might consider moving to this to solve to rule it out. E.g. use 'com.yourcomany.pulsemd' as your bundle id / app id.

Comment: That won't change it, its just a naming convention that is not mandatory. Yes there is name and identifier 
DistributionPulseMD Distribution.PulseMD

Comment: The only place where I can see Xcode putting in the wrong app id is in the build settings -> code signing -> provisioning profile is automatic, when i make that the correct bundle identifier it then says that profile doesn't with this team when in apple member center it is correct.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  And have a lot of experience with this process.  So I'm not sure what the issue is, but something funny is going on.  Thread on Apple support forums alludes to the same issue.  https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/34195  I'm hoping something surfaces soon to resolve this issue.